# C++ Calling a function that returns template type value

Tags: c++

I am trying to understand if it is possible to call a function that returns a template type value without explicitly specifying it in call statement?

Function I am trying to call is like this,

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<SomeClass<T>> createObjectInstance(InputData data) {
  if(data.type_str == "abc") {
    return createObjectInstanceImpl<ABC>(data);
  } else if(data.type_str == "def") {
    return createObjectInstanceImpl<DEF>(data);
  } else {
    // throw error
  } 
}
```

calling statement

```
const auto objectPtr = createObjectInstance(data);
// Do something with objectPtr
```

This does not compile, compiler complains it couldn't infer template argument.
Does the calling function need to resolve the type each time this is needed? Seems very cluttered to do that. Are there known design workarounds?

Comment: createObjectInstance<TheType>(data)

Comment: Polymorph functions have to be distinguishable by their function arguments. That is true for template functions as well. The return type cannot be deduced if there are no arguments which can be used for this.

Comment: @JVApen OP asked _without explicitly specifying it in call statement_. IMHO, the answer is No in this case.

Comment: @Scheff You are right, it needs to common interface and return that, or get the string as template argument and some if-constexpr stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to define the return type of a function at runtime, as your example tries to do.

When you define a function with a templated return value, the returned value can only be of one type.  And that type MUST be defined at compile time.

The only way your function may compile, is to have the type of the returned pointer be a base class of both `ABC` and `DEF`.  But then, you would not need a template function to achieve that goal.